Why is my sortablecontext dissapearing after removing all element from it dnd kit react
I have SortableContext for dopping my sweaters. But when I remove every sweater from one of them, it
dissapears and I cant put anything else in it. Im using dnd kit and react. Has this happened to anyone else?
Below are my component that I want to drag between sortablecontext and a component where I want to drop it that contain sortablecontext.
function Sweater({ sweater, folded, forFoundation, noStyle }) {
  const { id, sweaterImg, foldedSweater } = sweater;

  const {
    attributes,
    listeners,
    setNodeRef,
    transform,
    transition,
    isDragging,
  } = useSortable({ id, data: { type: "sweater", forFoundation, sweater } });

  const style = {
    transition,
    transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
  };

  if (isDragging) return null;

  return (
    <div ref={setNodeRef} {...attributes} {...listeners} style={style}>
      <img
        style={{ left: `${(id - 1) * 120}px` }}
        className={folded ? "foldedsweater__img" : "sweater__img"}
        src={folded ? foldedSweater : sweaterImg}
        alt="sweater"
      ></img>
    </div>
  );
}

function SingleFoundation({ foundationSweaters, forFoundation, name }) {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  const foundationSweatersIds = useMemo(
    () => foundationSweaters.map((col) => col.id),
    [foundationSweaters]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <InformationPopup
        showPopup={showPopup}
        close={() => setShowPopup(false)}
        name={name}
      />
      <div className="foundation__wrapper">
        <div className="information__wrapper">
          <a onClick={() => setShowPopup(true)}>
            <img
              className="information__img"
              src="src\assets\infoIcon.png"
              alt="informations"
            />{" "}
          </a>

          <a href="https://lampas92.hu/" target="_blank">
            {" "}
            <img
              className="link__img"
              src="src\assets\linkIcon.png"
              alt="informations"
            />{" "}
          </a>
        </div>
        <p className="sweaterscount__text">{foundationSweaters.length}</p>
        <h2 className="foundationname__text">{name} </h2>
        <SortableContext
          items={foundationSweatersIds}
          strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
        >
          <div className="soratable__wrapper">
            <div className="shelf__sortable">
              {foundationSweaters.length == 0 ? (
                <p>Nesto</p>
              ) : (
                foundationSweaters.map((sweater) => (
                  <Sweater
                    key={sweater.id}
                    sweater={sweater}
                    forFoundation={forFoundation}
                    folded={true}
                  />
                ))
              )}
            </div>
            <img src="src/assets/shelf.png" className="shelf" alt="shelf" />
          </div>
        </SortableContext>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

I tried giving fixed height to element inside the context but same thing happens
